# Is it possible to define the equivalent of python __getitem__ method in dart?

Tags: dart, class, methods

I am currently defining a class holding (among other things) a list as an attribute, in Dart.

I would like to access the items on an instance of this class without accessing the list attribute.

Would there be a way to define an "item getter" like it can be done in python through the `__getitem__` method?

For illustration:

```dart
class ClassHoldingList {
  const ClassHoldingList({required this.listAttribute});

  List<int> listAttribute;

  // I would like to be able to define this kind of definition or override
  @override
  int __getitem__(int index) => listAttribute[index];
}

instance = ClassHoldingList(listAttribute: [1, 2, 3, 4]);

print(instance[1]);  // '2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an "item getter" in a dart class by changing the [] operator like this:

```
operator [](index) => listAttribute[index];
```

You can also define a "item setter" like this:

```
operator []=(index, value) { listAttribute[index] = value; }
```

Comment: I did not have the opportunity to test it yet, but I will get back to you as soon as I got some time to check it up.

Comment: I tested it (only the getter, not the setter) and it worked like a charm!